# Why does the Stack Overflow Developer Survey not include Hong Kong?

Tags: discussion, survey

For the purpose of buying job postings, I'm trying to figure out whether Hong Kong software developers use Stack Overflow. Apparently there are [none](https://stackoverflow.com/research/developer-survey-2015#overview).

I imagine that Hong Kong was actually lumped together with China. This mistake would be easy to make for someone that has never been to the region. However, the Hong Kong languages, laws, culture, and economy are different than those China. The postal systems differ. The currencies differ. The passports differ. People cannot travel between these two regions without the appropriate visas, and these visas are not granted freely.

So if this guess is correct, can we fix this for next year?

(And is there someone I should contact about this?)

Comment: "I imagine that Hong Kong was actually lumped together with China." Yet somehow they were able to get Singapore right...

Comment: @BoltClock Fairly sure Singapore isn't a Chinese SAR. That said, I agree that HK should be separate, there's a significant sociocultural divide at work there.

Comment: @TJennings: I was just making a dig at how people get Singapore and China mixed up just as often anyway.